# SQL Syntax question

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to remember the syntax to change a date field into a string. I know I'm close but not 100% correct. Here is what I'm using so far: `TO_CHAR(FIELD_NAME)`. I'm using an Access database. The error I'm getting is: `undefined expression`. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It helps to specify exactly what SQL implementation you are using.  Microsoft SQL, DB2, MySql, Postgres or something else entirely.

Comment: @Joe _Im using an access database_ Looks like Access to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `CStr(dateField)` or `Format(dateField)` to convert.
Additionally you can add parameters to `Format()` to show it in a different format, such as:

`Format(dateField, "general date")   9/12/2010`
`Format(dateField, "long date")      Monday, September 12, 2011`

Comment: +1 nice edit I would have up voted earlier but I couldn't for some reason ;).

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer like 3 times, deleted it and then resurrected it once I got it right.

Comment: hmm I guess those edits were inside the grace period where they don't show up in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7392873/revisions) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using MS Access and its a date field you're probably not just looking to convert to string but to also format the Date. If that is indeed the case you'll want the Format function

```
SELECT Format ([DateCreate], "yyyy/mm/dd") AS Foo
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SQL Server, try out [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CONVERT function, like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateField, 100)
```

Here's a link that shows the different date formats you can use:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Using to_char in SQL Server would result in something like  `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1 'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Not `undefined expression`. Also the question was clear about the technology used

Comment: @Conrad Frix: I'm not using TO_CHAR, I'm converting to VARCHAR... Did you downvote the wrong answer??

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Tested - does not produce errors. Results is: `Apr 19 2010 9:30 AM`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The OP was asking an Access question. If you had noticed the error they were reporting when using `TO_CHAR` you would have known that it wasn't a SQL server question.

Comment: Yes, you're right on that front. I just didn't understand why you voted me down citing code I didn't use.

Answer (score -1):

I assume SQL Server as you're questions in the past are .NET Questions.

Use CONVERT
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx